# Flutter future builder duplicating document item at every refresh

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-futurebuilder

I am populating a list of orders from firestore database in flutter. but order screen is doubling the documents at every refresh. Kindly help.

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

class FullOrder extends StatelessWidget {
  const FullOrder({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    // it enable scrolling on small device
    return Center(
      child: FutureBuilder(
          future: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('orders').get(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {

            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done ||
                snapshot.hasData) {

              List<QueryDocumentSnapshot> docs = (snapshot.data! as QuerySnapshot).docs;
              return ListView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemCount: docs.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {

                    var data = docs[index].data();
                    var dataOrders = data['orders'] as List<dynamic>;
                    var mappedDataOrders = dataOrders.map((o) => (o as Map<String, dynamic>)).toList();

                    return Card(
                        child: Container(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4),
                          child: Column(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: [
                                Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                  children: [
                                    Text('Order Id: ${data['orderId']}'),
                                  ],
                                ),
                                Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                  child: Row(
                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                                    children: [
                                    Text('Order Date: ${DateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy').format(data['createdAt'].toDate())}'),
                                    Text('Order Time: ${DateFormat('hh:mm a').format(data['createdAt'].toDate())}'),
                                  ],),
                                ),
                                Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                                  child: Row(
                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                    children: [
                                      Text('Name: ${data['name']}', style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                                      Text('Contact: ${data['phoneNumber'].toString()}', style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                  children: [
                                    Column(
                                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                      children: [
                                        const Text('Delivery Slot', style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                                        Text('${data['deliverySlot']}'),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                    Column(
                                      children: [
                                        Text('Address: ${data['addressType']}', style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                                        Text('${data['address']}'),
                                        Text('${data['area']}'),
                                        Text('${data['city']}')
                                      ],
                                    )
                                  ],
                                ),
                                ...List.generate(
                                    mappedDataOrders.length,
                                        (index) {
                                      var order = mappedDataOrders[index] as Map<String, dynamic>;

                                      return Column(
                                        children: [
                                          Row(
                                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                            children: [
                                              Text(order['title']),
                                              Text(order['unit'].toString()),
                                              Text(order['quantity'].toString()),
                                              Text(order['price'].toString()),
                                            ],
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      );
                                    }
                                )
                              ]
                          ),
                        )
                    );
                  }
              );
            }

            return const Center(

                child: SizedBox(
                    width: 100,
                    height: 100,
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                        valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.black),
                        strokeWidth: 5
                    )
                )

            );
          }
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
When you convert the Database list to map instead of converting to toList() USE toSet(), this helps you out to filter out the duplicating item. 

{
```

// use toSet() to filter the duplicated items.
var mappedDataOrders = dataOrders.map((o) => (o as Map<String, dynamic>)).toSet();

```
}
```

Comment: `var order = mappedDataOrders[index];` error Try correcting the operator to an existing operator, or defining a '[]' operator.
                                  var order = mappedDataOrders[index];
                                                              ^

Comment: Try it like this  {  class Model {
  String name;

  Model({required this.name});
}

class Test {}

void main() {
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> model = [
    {'x': 1},
    {'y': 2},
  ];

  var x = model.map((e) => e).toList();
  var y = x[0];
  y.forEach(
    (key, value) => print(key),
  );
}
  }

Answer (score 0):

Use the .clear();  Because everytime you load youre map instead of restarting the counter id adds to it.

Where you create youre load mappedDataOrdes. You migth have it like this.

```
Future<List<Database>> searchDatabase() async{
    
    final url= Uri.https(_baseUrl, 'Database.json');
    final resp = await http.get(url);
    final Map<String,dynamic> databaseMap= jsonDecode(resp.body);
    ////This is where you migth use the .clear() this will reset the counter for the index and eliminate duplicate
  database.clear();   
    database.forEach((key, value) {
      final tempDatabase= Database.fromMap(value);
      tempDatabase.id=key;
      database.add(tempDatabase);
    });

 return negocio;
```

}